# Android facebook login wont go to next activity

Tags: android, facebook, android-intent, android-activity, facebook-login

I am trying to figure out how to make a simple login via facebook which then takes you to the next activity once logged in. Currently, it just takes you to a facebook logout page and i cant figure out why.

I have a startActivity line in the SignIn page under onSuccess but nothing happens.

I have 2 activities. One being SignIn and the other is Profile, which has a back button. I've been following the facebook tutorial here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android#

any and all insight/advice is appreciated.

here is my code

**SignIn**

```
package com.example.test;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.facebook.AccessToken;
import com.facebook.CallbackManager;
import com.facebook.FacebookCallback;
import com.facebook.FacebookException;
import com.facebook.login.LoginManager;
import com.facebook.login.LoginResult;
import com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class SignIn extends AppCompatActivity {

    private CallbackManager callbackManager;
    private static final String EMAIL = "email";
    private LoginButton login_button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.signin);

        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

        login_button = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        login_button.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList(EMAIL));

        // Callback registration
        login_button.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                // App code

                Intent intent = new Intent(SignIn.this, Profile.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                // App code
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                // App code
            }
        });

        LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager,
                new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                        // App code
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancel() {
                        // App code
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                        // App code
                    }
                });

        AccessToken accessToken = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
        boolean isLoggedIn = accessToken != null && !accessToken.isExpired();

        LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(this, Arrays.asList("public_profile"));

    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    }
}
```

**Profile**

```
package com.example.test;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Profile extends AppCompatActivity {


    Button backButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.backButton);



    public void backToSignIn(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SignIn.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you override the first callback when you  register another callback, try to remove second callback register

```
LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager,
            new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                    // App code
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancel() {
                    // App code
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                    // App code
                }
            });
```

or change

```
@Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                // App code
            }
```

to

```
 @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            // App code

            Intent intent = new Intent(SignIn.this, Profile.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
```

in second callback registered

Comment: that seems to be going in the right direction. i end up getting a Null Pointer Exception.     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.Window$Callback android.view.Window.getCallback()' on a null object reference

Comment: I think you have a bad structure in `Profile` you need to add `onCreate` method and set your `setContentView` e.g. 
`@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.profile);
}`

Comment: remember the lifecycle of activities [lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle) specific [onCreate](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#onCreate(android.os.Bundle))

Comment: Thanks @JosueAmador, those look promising! i'll give those a shot!!